# Best Method to process a list that is used as a parameter to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, list, stored-procedures

I have a List of item ids (12345,23456, etc) but there is about 7000 of them.
What I am doing is taking each item in the list and passing them to a stored procedure to get another number if it meets the criteria in the procedure. Heres the C# code:

```
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@itemId", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@division", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        foreach (var item in itemNumber)
        {
            cmd.Parameters["@itemId"].Value = item;
            cmd.Parameters["@division"].Value = CboRequestDivisions.SelectedValue;

            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                CboProductionOrder.Items.Add(reader[0].ToString());
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

and heres the stored proc:

```
Select replace(PRODID,'Prod-','') from PRODTABLE where itemID = @itemId and (PRODSTATUS ='0' or PRODSTATUS = '2' or PRODSTATUS = '3' or PRODSTATUS = '4') and Dimension2_ = @division order by PRODID asc
```

Calling this proc to find the results 7000 concurrent times is ridiculous. Is there a way to thread each item so I'm calling the procedure several times at once. Right now it takes about 20 minutes to go through the items

Comment: You are calling a stored procedure 7000 times? isn't there a better way you can do this? I don't necessarily suggest it, but you can make stored procedures take a `datatable` as a parameter which would drastically decrease your time to run this processing. You have to define a user-defined table in the Database though to use it

Comment: Take a look at SqlBulkCopy class. Then ETL to a staging table using the class and do an insert from select of the staging table

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to build a single parameter with all the items with a separator, and then use PARSE in SQL to work with them individually.

Another way to do it is by treating the parameter with the full item collection as a varchar, and build a query dinamically and then execute it with exec command.